# encrypted $HOME in 16.04

Tags: encryption, home-directory, debian

I'm having a home partition encrypted during the 16.04 installation and I'd like to know if it would be compatible with the install of a 18.04 seen that this support has been removed.

I'd like to know if it is also possible to change the system and use by example a debian testing or any other debian based distrib and keep the same home.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Anyways, the second question would be off-topic on askubuntu.

Comment: yes but in a sense its related. :)

Comment: Yes you can use a prior encrypted $HOME after upgrade; this system I'm replying on has $HOME encrypted prior to 18.04 and still works now (on 19.10). Yes you can switch to another distro and not lose your /home partition, however you'll have to test with regards encryption (and debian/other-distros are off-topic here) but I can say it'll work with official flavors of Ubuntu.

Comment: thx a lot for your user experience.